# How to traverse a binary tree in left right direction?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I want a solution where in a binary tree is traversed in alternate left right direction. Level order traversal is "1 2 3 4 5 6 7". With the required condition my output has to be in "1 2 3 7 6 5 4". Below is the code I have written. It is not correct.

```
public void traverseLevel(BinaryTreeNode root) {
    Queue<BinaryTreeNode> q = new LinkedList<BinaryTreeNode>();
    q.add(root);
    int c = 0;
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {

        root = q.poll();
        System.out.print(root.getData() + " ");
        if (c == 0) {
            c = 1;
            if (root.getLeft() != null) {
                q.add(root.getLeft());
            }
            if (root.getRight() != null) {
                q.add(root.getRight());
            }

        } else {
            c = 0;
            if (root.getRight() != null) {
                q.add(root.getRight());

            }
            if (root.getLeft() != null) {
                q.add(root.getLeft());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output am getting is "1 2 3 5 4 6 7"

Answer (score 3):

What i understand from your question is you want to print the tree in spiral order.

You can simply use two stacks

1. first stack for printing from left to right.
2. second stack for printing from right to left.

Starting from the root node, you have to store the children in one stack.
Hence for every iteration print nodes present in one stack. The next level is pushed in another stack.

Answer (score 2):

I'll trace your implementation for you. At first, your queue contains node 1.

1

You then insert its children into the queue, with the left one first because c is 0.

1 2 3

1 then exits the queue, so you're left with

2 3

Since you want to start at the right now, 3 would be the ideal starting point. HOWEVER, 2 comes first in your queue, so its children will be pushed first.

2 3 5 4, then 2 exits to form 3 5 4

It's at this point that 3 will push its children into the queue, with the left first because c is 0.

3 5 4 6 7

I think what you want to do is to have a queue and a stack, where the queue contains items to be printed, and the stack receives items removed from the queue. You can then pop each item in the stack and push their children into the queue.

For example, we start with 1 in the queue and an empty stack. We then remove 1 from the queue, print it, then push it into the stack. Then we pop 1 and insert its children into the queue left-first.

2 3

Next, we print 2 and put it in the stack. Same for 3. Now our stack contains

2 3

We then pop 3 from the stack and queue its children right-first this time. Then we pop 2 and do the same for its children. Our queue now contains

7 6 5 4

And then just repeat the process until you've reached all the leaves.

Also, one tip: c can be a boolean instead of a number because you only use 0 and 1 as values. It saves space that way. :)

Answer (score 1):

**following approach is in C++ using STL**

```
struct TreeNode // basic Tree Structure
{
int data;
TreeNode* leftchild;
TreeNode* rightchild;
}
void alternateLeftRight(TreeNode*root)
{
Stack<TreeNode*>currentLevel; // take two stacks 
Stack<TreeNode*>nextLevel;
currentLevel.push(root);
int LeftToRight=0;  // LeftToRight mean we will approach leftchild before rightchild, if LeftToRight=0 , in this case we will approach rightchild first
while(!currentLevel.empty())
{ 

 TreeNode*temp=currentLevel.top();
 cout<<temp->data<<" ";
 currentLevel.pop();
if(LeftToRight)
{
 if(temp->leftchild)nextLevel.push(leftchild);
 if(temp->rightchild)nextLevel.push(rightchild);
}
else
{
  if(temp->leftchild)nextLevel.push(rightchild);
  if(temp->rightchild)nextLevel.push(leftchild);
}

if(currentLevel.empty())
{
swap(currentLevel,nextLevel);
LeftToRight=1-LeftToRight;
}

}

}
```